# How to activate support for ANSI escape in terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, ruby, ansi

The ri tool of Ruby for the documentation offers the possibility to output ANSI escape sequences, but the terminal has to support it.

How is it possible to activate support for ANSI escape sequences in the Gnome terminal of Ubuntu? In a way that the command

```
$ri Symbol --formant=ansi
```

is correctly rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem related to LESS

Set up the environment variable.

```
export LESS="-eRiMX"
```

and It is fixed. For making it global, add it to your .bashrc file in your home folder.

Source :

http://excid3.com/blog/how-to-fix-esc-in-your-terminal/